# in ASP MVC Core how to Pass Parameter from ViewComponent to Parent

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am trying to pass a parameters value from ViewComponent to Parent View , without using ViewData , ViewBag or even session variable  , I know how to pass from Parent to viewcompoenent but can't still pass to parent , 
as an example : create Login ViewComponent (having User Name and Password as well as login Button) once the user press Login and is authenticated the component should pass "isAuthenticated" Parameter to the Parent View to show the menu...
your help is appreciated !
reagrds
Nahed

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you you are trying to achieve. May be there is a better way to do it.

Comment: I have created Login functionality using ViewComponent , once the user is Authenticated I need to pass isAuthenticated as a paremeter to the Parent View , I can use a session variable to save the value however I am trying to find the way passing the parameter to parent directly .Thx